# Index change in a recursive definition

Tags: recursion, index

Assume I have the following recursive definition:

```
Operator[H[y] Subscript[G, l][x]] = 
 l D[H[y], y] Subscript[G, l + 1][x] + 
(l + 1) D[H[y], y] Subscript[G, l - 1][x]
```

I would like to apply this operator twice, Operator^2.

How can one "teach" Mathematica to increase and decrease the index of the G function, as well as to take proper combination of the H function?

Can you please help to write such an operator in a proper way?

Thank you, 
Anna

Comment: I hink one can define operator[G[l_, x_] H[y_]] := (1 + l) G[-1 + l, x] H'[y] + l G[1 +l, x] H'[y] without loosing generality. to define the behavior of nested operator we must know if it is a linear operator i.e. can we assume that operator[a_+b_]:=operator[a]+operator[b]